# Data Binding: update a value from an animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, binding

I'd like to do something like this: when I click on a button an image starts rotating around its center. When I click on that button again, the animation stops. I'd like to two-way-bind the Angle property and retrieve it when the animation stops. The code is very simple, but the binding doesn't work. It only works in one-way, from the code to the xaml, but not from the xaml to the code (I can't get the Angle updated from the animation).

This is the xaml file:

```
<Page
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="Calculator.HubPage"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Calculator"
    xmlns:data="using:Calculator.Data"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="RotateImage">
            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="360" Duration="00:00:00.5" Storyboard.TargetName="rotateTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="Assets/spoon.gif" Stretch="None" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" Angle="{Binding ElementName=pageRoot, Path=RotationAngle, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Click me!" Click="Op_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And this is the C# class:

```
public sealed partial class HubPage : Page
    {                
        public static DependencyProperty RotationAngleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RotationAngle", typeof(double),
            typeof(HubPage), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

        private Boolean started;

        public double RotationAngle
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(RotationAngleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RotationAngleProperty, value); }
        }

        public HubPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();            
            started = false;

        }

        private void Op_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!started)
            {
                (Resources["RotateImage"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard).Begin();
            }
            else
            {
                (Resources["RotateImage"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard).Pause();                
            }
            started = !started;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me? Thank you!

**EDIT** to answer to **BradleyDotNET**:
Yes, after the animation starts the binding doesn't work anymore both directions. I'll try to add this:

```
private void Op_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!started)
            {
                (Resources["RotateImage"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard).Begin();
            }
            else
            {
                (Resources["RotateImage"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard).Pause();
                RotationAngle = 90;
            }
            started = !started;
        }
```

The `RotationAngle = 90;` is ignored from the image in the xaml file (the binding doesn't work anymore). But if I change `.Pause()` with `.Stop()` this way:

```
private void Op_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!started)
            {
                (Resources["RotateImage"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard).Begin();
            }
            else
            {
                (Resources["RotateImage"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard).Stop();
                RotationAngle = 90;
            }
            started = !started;
        }
```

The `RotationAngle = 90;` works and the image lays horizontal as I expect. It seems that the binding doesn't work during the animation.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if running that animation *cleared the binding entirely*. Are you sure *any* part of that binding still works after the animation runs?

Comment: Mmh... why aren't you surprised? I'm new to xaml, sorry. In few words I'd like to "retrieve the image angle when the animation stops". Can I do this in some way? Thank you.

Comment: Right, I just want to make sure I'm addressing the correct issue. Could you verify that the binding *fails entirely* (both directions) after the animation runs?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try to verify.

Comment: Ok, I verified. Please, read my EDIT and thank you for helping me.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like my initial guess was wrong... The behavior you are seeing *could* be related to the `FillBehavior` of the animation. That doesn't explain why a two-way wouldn't work though... Does the two-way work after the `Stop` variant?

Comment: Mmh... I can verify the c#-to-xaml data bind modifying the RotationAngle in my c# class as you can see in my edit after the .Stop(), but how can I verify the xaml-to-c# data bind? How can I modify the angle of the image from the xaml file?

Comment: Well, the bound value should equal the "To" value in the animation, so I would check that after stopping it. After double checking your animation, it should just be some random value.

Comment: If I .Stop() the animation the image Angle always returns to 0.

Comment: Hmm.... I'm really not sure. I'll think about it and let you know if I come up with anything though. As an aside, just drop the binding and read it directly. Its all View code anyways :)

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, but I'm really n00b: how can I "read it directly" as you say?

Comment: Just name the transform and do `MyRotationTransform.Angle` (or whatever name you gave it).

Answer (score 0):

Try this binding instead:

```
Angle="{Binding ElementName=pageRoot, Path=RotationAngle, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: Please don't phrase answers as questions. Answers need to *answer the question* not just ask the OP something (thats what comments are for). There actually is an answer in here, so I edited it for you. An explanation of why this answer (might?) work is always a good thing to include as well.